# QtQuick2 Video rendering quality and embedding QVideoWidget to Qml

Tags: c++, video, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am working on a Qml application based on the QtQuick2, and I am having problems with the Video component included in the QtMultimedia 5.0 module. The application is supposed to add video to Qml interface and most importantly is that any BLACK color (background, rectangle or object) must be REALLY BLACK so I can overlay other Qml components over the black areas.

When a video is played in the C++ QvideWidget, the video quality is good, and all the black area are really black, but when I use the QtQuick2 Video component, the quality is a little bit yellowish. I was able to do it easily in the Qt 4.8.7 with QtQuick1 using QDeclarativeItem and QGraphicProxyWidget, but since Qt5 changed the QtQuick2 way, I couldn't find a way to easily embedded widget.

I have made a custom QAbstractVideoSurface and set it as `QMediaPlay->setVideoOutput`, and paint it in QtQuickPaintedItem by grabbing QImage and calling update(), but still same. Even changed all qRGB below treshold of 16 to qRgb(0,0,0), but the result is bad, especially on fade-in or fade-out.

Is there any way I could fix this? Thanks in advance

[image: Video playing in VLC (good black background)]

[image: Video playing in QVideoWidget (good quality black background)]

[image: Video playing in Qml Video QtMultimedia 5.0]

**Edit 1: inserted code**

```
 import QtQuick 2.6
 import QtMultimedia 5.0

 Video{

    id: video
    width: root.width
    height: root.height

    property string src: "main.mp4"

    source: src
    autoLoad: true
    autoPlay: true
    fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectFit
  }
```

C++ Code with QVideoWidget

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
QVideoWidget *view = new QVideoWidget();

player->setVideoOutput(view);
player->play();


view->resize(700, 700);
view->show();
```

Custom QAbstractSurface

```
#include "videoframegrabber.h"

VideoFrameGrabber::VideoFrameGrabber(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractVideoSurface(parent)
    , imageFormat(QImage::Format_Invalid)
{
}

QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> VideoFrameGrabber::supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(handleType);
    return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>()
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV420P
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_UYVY
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUYV
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV21
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC1
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC2
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC3
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC4
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y8
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y16
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Jpeg
        << QVideoFrame::Format_CameraRaw
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AdobeDng;
}

bool VideoFrameGrabber::isFormatSupported(const QVideoSurfaceFormat &format) const
{
    const QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat());
    const QSize size = format.frameSize();

    return imageFormat != QImage::Format_Invalid
            && !size.isEmpty()
            && format.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer::NoHandle;
}

bool VideoFrameGrabber::start(const QVideoSurfaceFormat &format)
{
    const QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat());
    const QSize size = format.frameSize();

    if (imageFormat != QImage::Format_Invalid && !size.isEmpty()) {
        this->imageFormat = imageFormat;
        imageSize = size;
        sourceRect = format.viewport();

        QAbstractVideoSurface::start(format);

        //widget->updateGeometry();
        //updateVideoRect();

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void VideoFrameGrabber::stop()
{
    currentFrame = QVideoFrame();
    targetRect = QRect();

    QAbstractVideoSurface::stop();

    //widget->update();
}

bool VideoFrameGrabber::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
{
    if (frame.isValid())
    {
        QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);
        cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
        const QImage image(cloneFrame.bits(),
                           cloneFrame.width(),
                           cloneFrame.height(),
                           QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame .pixelFormat()));
        emit frameAvailable(image); // this is very important
        cloneFrame.unmap();
    }

    if (surfaceFormat().pixelFormat() != frame.pixelFormat()
            || surfaceFormat().frameSize() != frame.size()) {
        setError(IncorrectFormatError);
        stop();

        return false;
    } else {
        currentFrame = frame;

        //widget->repaint(targetRect);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: One difference might be the GPU driver video postprocessing that is applied in one case and not another. Check that any video processing by the GPU is turned off. On Windows this lies in the Intel/Nvidia/AMD GPU control panels (see e.g. [this link](https://forums.creativecow.net/docs/forums/post.php?forumid=2&postid=1015439&univpostid=1015439&pview=t) which suggests turning on full dynamic range in the Nvidia settings, in a different context granted, but I believe this might have to do with your problem). Please also show the code you use for both cases.

Comment: @rubenvb please check edit 1. how come this only effects Qml and not QVideoWidget?